# Given a special topology, how do compact sets look like

Tags: general-topology

I came across the following example of a topology on $\mathbb Z$:

> $$\mathcal T_{\mathbb Z} := \{M\in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z): M = \emptyset \quad\text{or}\quad M = \mathbb Z\quad\text{or}\quad (-1 \in M \,\wedge1 \notin M)\}$$ 
>   Give a characterisation of every non-finite compact set of $(\mathbb Z, \mathcal T_{\mathbb Z})$ .

Here's my thoughts:
- $\{-1\}$ is the only open set with just one element.
- $\mathcal T_{\mathbb Z}$ is not discrete since $\{1\}$ is not open.
- The only open sets are the ones containing $\{-1\}$ except $\mathbb Z$ itself.

I don't know, however, how I can think of compact sets on this Topology. Maybe because the concept of every open cover having a finite subcover is still kind of abstract to me. Can you give me any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z$ is compact, because every open covering must contain $Z$ itself. Analogously every subset of $Z\setminus\{-1\}$. But if $A$ is infinite containing $-1$, we can choose covering of the form $\{x,-1\}$, $x\in A$, which has no finite subcovering.

Comment: But $\mathbb Z$ itself does not have a finite subcover, does it?

Comment: @bavor42 One-element is finite. :-) Of course I don't know whether your "compact" is defined by subcovering or it must be also Hausdorff ($T_2$).

Comment: You are right of course, I just confused something, I got it now. My notion of compact is indeed defined by subcovering, so your answer is completely right! :)